# Computer freezing at a specific location (physical)

Tags: windows

I work at a University and we are having a completely baffling situation.  We have a computer at a specific location here that freezes up about every day, sometimes multiple times a day.  We couldn't figure it out on site and we took it to our shop to work on it.  There were no issues, we ran it for about 4 days.  We brought it back, and the issues came back immediately.
We replaced it with a new computer, and the same issues happened which made us think there was an electrical issue of some sort.  All of the electrical seems fine.  We had our electrician check all wiring and monitor it for surges, nothing.
To add further clarification, that old computer was moved off-site and is being used for the same purpose and the issue has disappeared.

Is there anything we could be missing?

Comment: definitely sounds electrical...  try using a UPS to clean the power or a different power supply

Comment: Different psu wont help, it does it for any pc they use there.

Comment: 1) A bad/intermittent network connection could conceivably cause a computer to hang. 2) So could strong electromagnetic interference (e.g. http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1955326/extremely-strange-behavior-charging-phone-crash.html). 3) The lab cat could be sleeping or dancing on the keyboard.

Comment: Maybe an automated attack over LAN? Did you try run it without LAN connection?

Comment: More like a lab rat....personally i think it is a time traveler doing it.

Comment: Maybe there is a microwave oven too close, or a nuke reactor.....

Comment: If you use a laptop on battery power in that location, does that fail too? Do the failures coincide with anything?

Comment: I am reminded of the "Magic/More Magic" Toggle Switch story: http://catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html

Comment: I just had a thought: did you use the same power cable each time? It would be easy to leave the same one plugged in and only swap the computer. If it now works, dispose of the old power lead.

Comment: They workers are in cubicles.  The kind that you permanently wire and have their own outlets.  I just realized that may be the issue.  I'm going to try and plug it into a standard wall receptacle and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there anything we could be missing?"

Yes, connect a UPS to that electrical outlet and plug the PC into the ups, see if the freezes stop.

A more expensive UPS that does power conditioning would be a better choice but they are more expensive than ones that do not.

Comment: We do have an APC ups attached to each one, although I'm not sure if it does power conditioning at all.  One other thing I failed to mention is that everyone is in cubicles, and the cubicles are permanently wired.  It could be some internal wiring issue inside those that could be the problem.  Maybe I can convince someone to take one of those apart.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the case is properly grounded as if it isn't [it can pick up RF](http://www.epanorama.net/documents/pc/ungrounded_pc.html) interference and static discharge, both of which could describe your problem.